# Net.WebClient Error - Is that Hosting Based?

Tags: c#, vb.net, webclient, webrequest

Im getting  this error :
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Code was simlpy, just trying to get content of specified url, i think the problem can be server based. Because when i tried to get data from 
http://ahgsql.5gbfree.com/test.te
my program can show "TEST"

but when i tried to get data from other server of mine, : it gives that error.
http://panelyt.com/test.te

Here is my code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
     Button1.Click
      Dim linkalan As New Net.WebClient
      Dim content As String = linkalan.DownloadString(TextBox1.Text)
     TextBox2.Text = content

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your url must be wrong.  This code works :         Dim url As String = "http://ahgsql.5gbfree.com/test.te"
        Dim linkalan As New Net.WebClient
        Dim str As String = linkalan.DownloadString(url)

Comment: There is a script error in (http://panelyt.com/test.te)  The first server responds "TEST", the second responds "VEVTVA==" and  the stream is an octet-stream, not plain text.

Comment: I mean, the response is Base64 encoded (VEVTVA== is = to TEST encoded)

Answer (score 0):

**The .NET HTTP implementation tries to keep the connection alive as long as possible in order to avoid the overhead of creating a new conneciton.**  *If the server decides to close the connection without notifying the client you may see this error.*  In general, you need to catch these exceptions in your application and create a new connections as necessary.  The client proxy code is not really related other than by the fact that it uses the .NET HTTP implementation.

There is a server side connection timeout in ASP.NET that you can configure, and it may be causing this problem.

Comment: Yeah but, there is more than 100 customers who using my software and some of them cant reach me. What can we do in hosting? i m using reseller with whm and cpanel

Comment: What I would have done, is check for the exception and then reopen the connection